# How to add column to SELECT OUTER JOIN that relies on an association table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a join that pulls information from two different tables:

```
SELECT [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type] 
FROM 
[Theme] Left Outer Join [ThemeType] ON [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] = [ThemeType].[PK_ThemeType]
ORDER BY [Theme].[Name] ASC
```

I have a third table called ProductTheme. This table has 3 columns, a PK, a productId and a ThemeId. ProductId is a foreign key which is the primary key of the product in the product table. The themeId is a FK which is the PK in the Theme table. This table holds the associated of products and themes.

I have a fourth table called Product.

In the above query I want to return what is currently being returned but an additional column as well. This column is the associated product (the product associated to the theme that is being pulled).

How can I accomplish this?

Edit:

ProductTheme table:

[image]

Comment: Your ProductTheme table describes a many to many relation as stated (are there unmentioned unique constraints?). Are you asking to somehow  select only one product for a given theme? If so, what are the criteria for which product should be chosen?

Comment: Yes, one product per theme. The criteria is the ProductTheme table.  For each theme it lists a foreign key integer, this integer is the PK on the Product table and has an associated varchar I want to list as one of the columns.

Comment: In your sample data, Theme 2 is associated with Products 1 and 2. Which product gets returned for the theme? How do you decide? Just the keys in the association table are not enough. You would get multiple rows for each theme; one for each associated product.

Comment: In that case I would like to have any of these multiples as one string in the same column separated by a comma